# How can I have about 1000 Android virtual devices to test "Push Notification"?

Tags: android

I want to have 1000 Android virtual device to test my project, but I can create 2 Android virtual device with my laptop. So how can i do?

Comment: Why do you need so many test devices ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily have such a test environment by yourself. But AFAIK there is an existing company that providing such service. Please refer to the link http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/services/android

Following is the statement from the website:

Developing applications for android? Perfecto Mobile's Android Cloud enables you to test your mobile apps via the web on dozens of REAL Android-based devices, operating in LIVE mobile networks in the US, UK, Canada, France and Israel.

Comment: Please rewrite in more neutral way before anyone flags this as spam.

Comment: This is not spam or advertising, this is a proper answer to the question.

Comment: At least the word FREE must be not in all capitals to see this as not an advertisement, but also remaining text looks as overall promotional.

Comment: I have removed the tendentious expressions.